# What is 'search: 2' for in ldapsearch results?

Tags: ldap

At the end of my ldapsearch results I always get something like the following:

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

I know what the rest of it is doing, but I can't find any info on what the `search: 2` line signifies. Any ideas? Is it the message ID? (with msgId:1 being the bind I guess)

(sigh, less than 200 rep means 'ldapsearch' isn't a valid tag...)

Comment: The commented LDIF output of the old OpenLDAP search tool can be repressed with the -L, -LL, or -LLL command line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2` is indeed the messageID of the `search` operation.

From the source code of OpenLDAP, file `clients/tools/ldapsearch.c`, function [`print_result()`](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob;f=clients/tools/ldapsearch.c;h=068acb3e1b5e30485409e7ef5dffaef49fd518a9;hb=HEAD#l1822):

```
1823         if( search ) {
1824                 if ( ldif < 2 ) {
1825                         printf(_("# search result\n"));
1826                 }
1827                 if ( ldif < 1 ) {
1828                         printf("%s: %d\n", _("search"), ldap_msgid(result) );
1829                 }
1830         }
```

You can verify this with a packet sniffer such as Wireshark. If, for example, SASL GSSAPI authentication is used, then the search operation will be #5, resulting in `search: 5`.